# Summed Scan - wrong results if large number of threads

Tags: cuda

Inspired by the implementation of sum scan algorithm described [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html), I tried to implement it the following way:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void count_zeros_shared(int N, int M, int* data)
{
    __shared__ unsigned s_offset[1024];

    for (int s = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; s < N; s += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        // count non-zero values
        unsigned count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            if (data[s + N * j] != 0)
                ++count;
        }
        s_offset[threadIdx.x] = count;

        if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
            printf("s_offset [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);

        // reduce offset
        for (int shift = 1; shift < blockDim.x; shift += shift)
        {
            __syncthreads();
            if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
            {
                s_offset[threadIdx.x] += s_offset[threadIdx.x - shift];
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
        if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
            printf("s_offset_acc [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);
    }
}

#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int NTH = 1024; // FAULTY case by default to answer request within comments
    if (argc > 1) NTH = ::atoi(argv[1]);

    cudaError_t cuerr;

    int* values;
    int N = 1024 * 48, M = 448;

    cuerr = ::cudaMallocManaged(&values, N*M * sizeof(int)) ;
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

    int count = 0;

    ::srand(42);

    for (int k = 0; k < N*M; ++k)
    {
        if ((rand() % 7) == 0) values[k] = ++count ; 
        else values[k] = 0;
    }

    count_zeros_shared <<< N / NTH, NTH >>> (N, M, values);
    cuerr = ::cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

    return ::cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

When executing it with 128threads per block, results are good, however, beyond 128 threads, results get wrong in the shared array beyond entry 128.

The code does not seem to illustrate any threshold effect at 128, though there seems to be one.

Compilation ptxinfo:

```
1>  ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z18count_zeros_sharediiPi' for 'sm_61' 
1>  ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z18count_zeros_sharediiPi 
1>      8 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads 
1>  ptxas info    : Used 25 registers, 8 bytes cumulative stack size, 4096 bytes smem, 336 bytes cmem[0]
```

Execution on GeForce 1060M, compiled with CUDA 9.0, targeting cc 6.1 in debug on Windows 10.

The `__syncthreads()` routine is called in appropriate locations, however, since CUDA 9.0, its behavior may have changed. Am I missing something here ?

## SUPPLEMENTAL INFO

compilation on linux :

```
$> nvcc -G main.cu -arch sm_61
```

Running on GeForce GTX 1080 results is similar issues

however,

```
$> nvcc main.cu -arch sm_61
```

Results look good.

Comment: How about an actual [MCVE]?

Comment: @talonmies, just edited the post to include an MCVE.

Comment: Just so I understand this -- now you are saying that the problem occurs with more than 128 threads (not 256 like before), and only when compiling for debugging? Have you tried declaring the shared memory buffer as volatile?

Comment: @talonmies, Well, I tested within a complete app using the above code snippet. In the reproducer, with other values it does not even work with 256 threads, yet works with 128. Hence the modified text. I understand this is misleading, but I wanted the post to be consistent.

Comment: 1. Please provide an example code in the failing configuration, not the passing configuration.  2. Please provide an example code that actually prints out results.  3. Please tell me what results you see in the failing case, and what results you expect to see.

Comment: Probably not related to the question here, but note that in the gpu gems chapter 39 article you linked, most of the code treatment deals with algorithm development that only works for a code utilizing a single threadblock. It will not give correct results in other cases.  Towards the end of that chapter/treatment (39.2.4), it discusses how to extend to the multi-threadblock case, but your code doesn't appear to comprehend that.  It's necessary for this type of treatment to do a grid-wide sync, and in the time that chapter was written, this would have been done using multiple kernel launches.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, 1. the failing configuration is obtained with NTH=1024 or calling the main with 1024 as first argument. I will amend the MCVE accordingly. 2. The code actually prints out results. (printf does work in CUDA). 3. The results depend on the implementation of the standard library (differ on windows and linux). I do understand your doubts and will do all my best to suit you with maximal information.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, re the GPU GEMS reference. I am using the first algorithm which counts values for a single block. The values are with a single block and no global count of number of non zero values. I am very much aware of the fact that cooperative groups did not exist at that time and global GPU sync was at first considered impossible and then not recommended in the proposed implementations.

Comment: If you run your code with `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ...` you will find that race conditions are reported.  These reported race conditions are for reads and writes *in the same line of code*.  I think if you study this line of code:  `s_offset[threadIdx.x] += s_offset[threadIdx.x - shift];` you will conclude that there is an inherent race condition.

Comment: I don't think the sweep pattern you want is achievable with an in-place scan without race conditions.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, can you place your comment in an answer to close it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a race condition at this point:

```
    for (int shift = 1; shift < blockDim.x; shift += shift)
    {
        __syncthreads();
        if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
        {
            s_offset[threadIdx.x] += s_offset[threadIdx.x - shift];
            ^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^
            write op                 read op
```

If we consider the case where `shift` = 1, then thread 1, 2, 3, 4,... will all be participating.  Thread 1 wants to read location 0, and add it to location 1.  Thread 2 wants to read location 1 and add it to location 2.  The order of these operations (and likewise through the rest of the threadblock) will affect the results.

This is discoverable by running the code with `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ...` although it apparently depends on not using `-G` (see below).

I assume you are trying to implement the stepped sweep pattern indicated in figure 39-2 [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html).  In that case, I don't have a trivial modification of the code to suggest to fix this using an in-place sweep, and still avoid the race condition.  If we do an out-of-place sweep, we can avoid the race condition.  The following example demonstrates that:

```
$ cat t271.cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void count_zeros_shared(int N, int M, int* data)
{
    __shared__ unsigned s_offset[1024];
    __shared__ unsigned s_offset2[1024];

    for (int s = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; s < N; s += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        // count non-zero values
        unsigned count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            if (data[s + N * j] != 0)
                ++count;
        }
        s_offset[threadIdx.x] = count;

//        if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
        if (s == 1023)
            printf("s_offset [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);

        // reduce offset
        for (int shift = 1; shift < blockDim.x; shift += shift)
        {
            s_offset2[threadIdx.x] = s_offset[threadIdx.x];
            __syncthreads();
            if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
            {
                s_offset[threadIdx.x] += s_offset2[threadIdx.x - shift];
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }
//        if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
        if (s == 1023)
            printf("s_offset_acc [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);
    }
}

#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int NTH = 128;
    if (argc > 1) NTH = ::atoi(argv[1]);

    cudaError_t cuerr;

    int* values;
    int N = 1024 * 48, M = 448;

    cuerr = ::cudaMallocManaged(&values, N*M * sizeof(int)) ;
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

    int count = 0;

    ::srand(42);

    for (int k = 0; k < N*M; ++k)
    {
        if ((rand() % 7) == 0) values[k] = ++count ;
        else values[k] = 0;
    }

    printf("count = %d\n", count);
    count_zeros_shared <<< N / NTH, NTH >>> (N, M, values);
    cuerr = ::cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

    return ::cudaDeviceReset();
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o t271 t271.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t271 1024
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
count = 3145571
s_offset [1023] = 73
s_offset_acc [1023] = 65571
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ./t271 1024
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
count = 3145571
s_offset [1023] = 73
s_offset_acc [1023] = 65571
========= RACECHECK SUMMARY: 0 hazards displayed (0 errors, 0 warnings)
$
```

I'm sure it's not "optimal", but this whole exercise is not "optimal".  If you want fast scans, use [thrust](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__prefixsums.html) or [cub](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/index.html).

Responding to a question in the comments: I agree that compiling with or without the `-G` (device debug code generation) switch seems to impact whether or not `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ...` reports a hazard or not.  On linux CUDA 9.0, GTX960 (cc5.2), I have the following test case using a minor variant of the original supplied code:

```
$ cat t271.cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void count_zeros_shared(int N, int M, int* data)
{
    __shared__ unsigned s_offset[1024];
#ifdef FIX
    __shared__ unsigned s_offset2[1024];
#endif
    for (int s = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; s < N; s += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        // count non-zero values
        unsigned count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            if (data[s + N * j] != 0)
                ++count;
        }
        s_offset[threadIdx.x] = count;

//        if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
        if (s == 1023)
            printf("s_offset [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);

        // reduce offset
#ifndef FIX
        for (int shift = 1; shift < blockDim.x; shift += shift)
        {
            __syncthreads();
            if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
            {
                s_offset[threadIdx.x] += s_offset[threadIdx.x - shift];  //line 34
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
#else
        for (int shift = 1; shift < blockDim.x; shift += shift)
        {
            s_offset2[threadIdx.x] = s_offset[threadIdx.x];
            __syncthreads();
            if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
            {
                s_offset[threadIdx.x] += s_offset2[threadIdx.x - shift];
            }
            __syncthreads();
        }
#endif
//        if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
        if (s == 1023)
            printf("s_offset_acc [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);
    }
}

#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int NTH = 128;
    if (argc > 1) NTH = ::atoi(argv[1]);

    cudaError_t cuerr;

    int* values;
    int N = 1024 * 48, M = 448;

    cuerr = ::cudaMallocManaged(&values, N*M * sizeof(int)) ;
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

    int count = 0;

    ::srand(42);

    for (int k = 0; k < N*M; ++k)
    {
        if ((rand() % 7) == 0) values[k] = ++count ;
        else values[k] = 0;
    }

    printf("count = %d\n", count);
    count_zeros_shared <<< N / NTH, NTH >>> (N, M, values);
    cuerr = ::cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

    return ::cudaDeviceReset();
}
$ nvcc -G -arch=sm_52 -o t271 t271.cu
$ cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ./t271 1024
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
count = 3145571
s_offset [1023] = 73
s_offset_acc [1023] = 65571
========= RACECHECK SUMMARY: 0 hazards displayed (0 errors, 0 warnings)
$ nvcc -lineinfo -arch=sm_52 -o t271 t271.cu
$ cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ./t271 1024
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
count = 3145571
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [236072 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [1992 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [2369 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [232728 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [913 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [233479 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [1841 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [239007 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [1833 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [228636 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [1689 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [225456 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [2177 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [151696 hazards]
=========
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [1009 hazards]
=========
s_offset [1023] = 73
s_offset_acc [1023] = 65571
========= ERROR: Race reported between Read access at 0x00000bb0 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*)
=========     and Write access at 0x00000bc8 in /home/bob/misc/t271.cu:34:count_zeros_shared(int, int, int*) [8064 hazards]
=========
========= RACECHECK SUMMARY: 16 hazards displayed (16 errors, 0 warnings)
$
```

We see that compiling with `-G`, no race condition is reported by `cuda-memcheck`.  Without that switch, the race condition is reported.  I don't really have an explanation for this at this time.  I see two possibilities:

1. a bug in `cuda-memcheck`
2. some characteristic of code generation with `-G` that somehow fully obscures the race condition from the tool.  I'm not sure what that would be, exactly.

Comment: as explained in the other answer, the cuda-memcheck tool did not help.

Comment: If you remove the `-G` switch while compiling, I don't think running cuda-memcheck will hide the issue or fail to report the hazard.

Comment: This is the output I am experiencing. Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: I've updated my answer with elaboration on what I see with/without `-G`

Comment: Thank you for these details. There seems to be something fishy with this example and cuda memcheck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RobertCrovella answer, I changed the code to avoid the race condition (adding it here for completeness):

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void init_kernel(unsigned* totalcount)
{
        totalcount [threadIdx.x] = 0;
}

#define TRACE 0

__global__ void count_zeros_shared(int N, int M, int* data, unsigned* totalcount)
{
        __shared__ unsigned s_offset[1024];

        for (int s = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; s < N; s += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
        {
                // count non-zero values
                unsigned count = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
                {
                        if (data[s + N * j] != 0)
                                ++count;
                }
                s_offset[threadIdx.x] = count;

                #if TRACE
                if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
                        printf("s_offset [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);
                #endif

                // reduce offset
                for (int shift = 1; shift < blockDim.x; shift += shift)
                {
                        __syncthreads();

                        #if 0 // race condition version

                        if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
                        {
                                s_offset[threadIdx.x] += s_offset[threadIdx.x - shift];
                        }

                        #else

                        int val = s_offset[threadIdx.x];
                        if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
                        {
                                val += s_offset[threadIdx.x - shift] ;
                        }
                        __syncthreads();
                        if (threadIdx.x >= shift)
                        {
                                s_offset[threadIdx.x] = val ;
                        }

                        #endif
                }
                __syncthreads();

                #if TRACE
                if ((s - threadIdx.x) == 0)
                        printf("s_offset_acc [%d] = %d\n", threadIdx.x, s_offset[threadIdx.x]);
                #endif

                if (threadIdx.x == 0)
                        atomicAdd(totalcount, s_offset[blockDim.x - 1]);

                __syncthreads();
        }

}

__global__ void printsum_kernel(int N, unsigned* totalcount)
{
        for (int NTH = 32 ; NTH <= 1024 ; NTH *= 2)
                printf("GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = %d] = %d\n", NTH, totalcount[(NTH / 32) - 1]);
}


#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        cudaError_t cuerr;

        int* values;
        unsigned* totalcount;
        int N = 1024 * 48, M = 448;

        cuerr = ::cudaMalloc(&totalcount, (1024/32) * sizeof(unsigned)) ;
        if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

        cuerr = ::cudaMallocManaged(&values, N*M * sizeof(int)) ;
        if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

        int count = 0;

        ::srand(42);

        for (int k = 0; k < N*M; ++k)
        {
                if ((rand() % 7) == 0) values[k] = ++count ;
                else values[k] = 0;
        }

        init_kernel << < 1, 1024/32 >> > (totalcount);
        cuerr = ::cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

        for (int NTH = 32; NTH <= 1024; NTH *= 2)
        {
                printf("RUNNING %d threads per block\n", NTH);

                count_zeros_shared << < N / NTH, NTH >> > (N, M, values, totalcount + ((NTH / 32) - 1));
                cuerr = ::cudaDeviceSynchronize();
                if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;
        }

        printsum_kernel << < 1, 1 >> > (1024/32, totalcount);
        cuerr = ::cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if (cuerr != cudaSuccess) return cuerr;

        printf("GROUND TRUTH TOTAL COUNT = %d\n", count);

        return ::cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

However, the cuda-memcheck tool behaved in a misleading way:

```
$> nvcc -G main3.cu -arch sm_61 -o a3.out
$>  cuda-memcheck --version
CUDA-MEMCHECK version 9.0.176 ID:(44)
$> cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck ./a3.out
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
RUNNING 32 threads per block
RUNNING 64 threads per block
RUNNING 128 threads per block
RUNNING 256 threads per block
RUNNING 512 threads per block
RUNNING 1024 threads per block
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 32] = 3145571
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 64] = 3145571
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 128] = 3145571
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 256] = 3145571
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 512] = 3145571
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 1024] = 3145571
GROUND TRUTH TOTAL COUNT = 3145571
========= RACECHECK SUMMARY: 0 hazards displayed (0 errors, 0 warnings)
$> ./a3.out
RUNNING 32 threads per block
RUNNING 64 threads per block
RUNNING 128 threads per block
RUNNING 256 threads per block
RUNNING 512 threads per block
RUNNING 1024 threads per block
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 32] = 3145571
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 64] = 3145571
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 128] = 3161857
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 256] = 3200816
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 512] = 3231303
GPU TOTAL COUNT [BlockDIM = 1024] = 3925122
GROUND TRUTH TOTAL COUNT = 3145571

$> nvidia-smi
Fri Jan  5 18:29:33 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.98                 Driver Version: 384.98                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   44C    P0    39W / 180W |      0MiB /  8112MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Running cuda-memcheck actually hides the issue.

The code version without the race condition works fine, at the expense of a supplemental `syncthreads` (but no supplemental shared memory).